# SQL Server 2008 _ group by + incremental

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need your help for this case :

(I work on SQL Server 2008)

Table :

```
IdProj      DocType     NumDoc
00265       PC          1
00265       PC          1
00268       PC          1
00268       PC          1
00268       PC          1
00268       PC          1
00268       PC          1
00370       PC          1
00370       PC          1
00370       PC          1
```

I would like to obtain :

```
IdProj      DocType     NumDoc
00265       PC          2
00265       PC          3
00268       PC          2
00268       PC          3
00268       PC          4
00268       PC          5
00268       PC          6
00370       PC          2
00370       PC          3
00370       PC          4
```

I suppose a group by IdProj and incremental routine is necessary but I don't have the solution yet. Can anybody give me any help please ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdProj  ORDER BY IdProj) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET NumDoc = 1 + RN
```

There is nothing shown in the question that indicates any particular ordering is required within a partition so ordering by the same value as the partition will do this arbitrarily.